# Creating snapshot tests with Vitest for Lit components

Tags: typescript, lit, vitest, snapshot-testing

I see some tutorials with React but am unclear how this would work w/ Lit. Specifically is there something like the react-test-renderer but for Lit?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { it, describe, expect } from 'vitest';
import { shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import App from '@/App.vue'

describe('App', () => {

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('renders the correct markup', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('router-view')
  })
})
```